# How to use this SMS plugin in my ionic application?

Tags: android, cordova, sms, ionic-framework

I am trying to use this sms plugin - https://github.com/Ivanezko/Phonegap-SMS in my ionic android application. I am following the Readme documentation to install the plugin. In the second step author asked to do -

```
Require the plugin module

var smsplugin = cordova.require("info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin.smsplugin");
```

What this statement means and where should I include this code to make use of this plugin?

I tried to do this in my controller file and its giving error cordova is not defined.

I tried debugging a little more in an emulator and the error given in the require statement is - ***module info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin.smsplugin is not found.***

Comment: You are using an outdated plugin with no support. I will suggest you to use latest one. like this https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

Comment: the problem is that the given plugin dint support sms recieve. Thats why I was searching for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

First solution: 1. check that this plugin is wrapped by http://ngcordova.com/.

Second solution: 2. write wrapper = angular factory:

```
.factory('factoryname', ['$q', '$window','$state', function ($q,$window, $state) {
 return {
  function1: function () {
        var q = $q.defer();
        if (!$window.cordova) {
          q.reject('Not supported without cordova.js');
        } else {
          secrettext.function1();
         return q.promise;
      },
```

3th solutions: add ['$window'] dependency to module you want use plugin. and use secrettext.function1();

*sectretext its clobbers from plugin xml

4 th solutions copy and paste this js code into you angular code on top of it and use function1();